# Navigation from UIViewController to UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4, xcode4.2

I am trying to move to `UITableView` named Cart from `UIView` by clicking on right bar button item , the button action event i wrote

```
Cart *crtObj=[[Cart alloc]initWithNibName:@"Cart" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:crtObj animated:YES];
[crtObj release];
```

And from the same Bar by clicking on left bar button i am navigating previous `tableView` which works properly, the code for the same is

`self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

I tried a lot please suggest something?

Comment: Can you post the code you use to initialize the button and the target of the tap on the button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:crtObj animated:YES];

//presentModalViewController

try this

```
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:crtObj animated:YES]
```

Comment: I tried that too if i try to move another ViewController named CartView the code is... CartView *crtObj=[[CartView alloc]initWithNibName:@"Cart" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:crtObj animated:YES];
    [crtObj release]; Then also its not working , what can be problem in navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why u have to use [self.navigationController presentModalViewController]
but not [self.navigationController pushViewController:crtObj animated:YES].

They are different.

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:ControllerA] will simply pull up a view of ControllerA from the bottom of ur screen. ControllerA will not be related the controllers those u are navigating along. (I am not sure if this method works)

[self.navigationController pushViewController:ControllerA animated:YES] will push ControllerA to the navigationController and it's stored with the controllers those u are navigating along in sequence.

i suggest using the second one because the structure of ur apps will be simpler.

but if u still want to use the first way. Maybe you can try like this:

Assume u have now navigated to ControllerA, and wanna show up Controller B
call [ControllerA presentModalViewController:ControllerB] instead